# iOS-Xamarin, branch.io, universal links Integration issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios9, branch.io, ios-universal-links

Am integrating branch.io to my iOS app which is being developed in Xamarin, without Forms.
Followed the steps mentioned in SDK integration.

- Added the **Branch** Xamarin SDK as a NuGet package
- branch_key added in Info.plist
- Added URL scheme in Xamarin
- Enabled Universal Links in branch.io portal
- Added code for initialization and delegates for branch.io
- Enabled Associated Domains in developer portal
- Enabled Associated Domains in xamarin studio and added domains applinks:bnc.lt

  *Ensure that the correct build target is checked in the right sidebar.*
  Am not sure how to do that in xamarin. By default the Entitlements.plist file is specified in configuration.
- Enabled Universal Links in branch dashboard
- Specified bundle identifier and Apple App prefix properly.
- Created a marketing link, and tapped the link from messages app.
- Which routes to safari with a dummy page from bnc.lt, with option of 'Get the app'

Any information on this would be greatly appreciable. Thanks!

Tested in

Device: iPhone6S+, iOS9.1

Device: iPhone6s, iOS9.4

**Update**

We had a custom link label for the all the marketing links, which should be kept empty to support Universal Links. The format of the market link would be bnc.lt/«four-letter-identifier»/«link-hash»

Comment: Alex with Branch here: could you confirm that the *Bundle Identifier* in `info.plist` matches exactly what you used in the Apple Developer Portal? If not, you'll want to [update that](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Set_Entitlements_in_your_Xamarin.iOS_Project). If still no luck, it's possible your Provisioning Profile is missing the Associated Domains entitlement — you may need to [create a new one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/#Creating_a_Development_Provisioning_Profile)

Comment: @AlexBauer, 
1. Bundle Identifier ins Info.plist matches with Apple Developer portal.
2. Provisioning profile is created after enabling associated domains entitlements and being used in the project.

Still the app doesn't open the app, instead redirects to appstore.

Comment: @AlexBauer Checked the link in Apple Validator, https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/

and the link looks good, everything passed. 

The problem is:

Actual Behaviour: MarketingLink (Notes app) -> Tap -> Launches Safari (Appstore Page).

Expected Behaviour: MarketingLink (Notes app) -> Tap -> Open the Actual application installed in the device.

Comment: Hmmm...the Apple Validator just checks server configuration, so unfortunately it's only part of equation. Would you mind submitting a [support ticket](http://support.branch.io) for this? That way we can check the back-end settings for your app and get things resolved more efficiently. I'll post an answer back here once we figure out the best solution.

Comment: @AlexBauer Got it working with the help Jean Weatherwax, Integration Engineer from Branch.
We had a custom link label for the all the marketing links. Which should be kept empty to support Universal Links. The format of the market link would be  https://bnc.lt/«four-letter-identifier»/«link-hash»

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense! I think you should be able to use custom link labels  with marketing links if you set up a [custom link domain](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/dashboard-guide/guide/#setting-a-custom-link-domain), in case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a note here to help anyone coming across this ticket and thinking they may have a similar issues:

The default Branch link domain for all apps until early 2016 was "bnc.lt." To support Universal Linking, all Branch apps using this bnc.lt domain had entries in a single Apple-App-Site-association (AASA) file. To uniquely identify apps in this AASA file, Branch relied on a four-letter alpha identifier in each link: https://bnc.lt/«four-letter-identifier»/«link-hash»

Branch allows partners to replace the "«four-letter-identifier»/«link-hash»" portion of bnc.lt links with custom aliases ("https://bnc.lt/mylink," for example), however doing so makes it impossible for the app to be identified in the AASA file - meaning that such links cannot function as Universal Links.

Branch introduced app.link domains in early 2016 to replace bnc.lt. The limitation regarding Universal Links and link aliases described here does not affect app.link domains.